# limit superior of function

Tags: analysis

Let $f : [2, \infty) \to [0,1)$ is a function with $$f(x) = \dfrac{\sqrt{4 + \left[\ln(1 + \sqrt{x^2 - 4})\right]^2} - 2}{x-2}$$ for all $x \in [2, \infty)$. Prove that, for all $x \in (2, \infty)$, the function satisfies $\limsup_{s \to x^+} f(s) < 1$.

Comment: This function is not well defined at $x=2$.

Comment: disregarding the point $x=2$ where the function is not defined the question is equivalent to show that the function is bounded by one, because it is continuous, and that it doesn't take this value in it domain

Answer (score 1):

HINT: note that for $x>2$
$$
f(x)<1\iff \log(1+\sqrt{x^2-4})<\sqrt{x^2-4}\iff \log(1+y)<y
$$
for $y>0$.

Comment: this just prove that $1$ is the upper bound, but how to prove that supremum $f(x) < 1$ ?

Comment: @asrida you dont need to prove that the supremum of $f$ in it domain is less than $1$. If $f$ is continuous then $$\lim_{x\to c}f(x)=\limsup_{x\to c}f(x)=\liminf_{x\to c}f(x)=f(c)$$

Comment: Oh i see, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

If you consider the function
$$f(x) = \dfrac{\sqrt{4 + \left[\ln(1 + \sqrt{x^2 - 4})\right]^2} - 2}{x-2}$$ the first problem is its behavior around $x=2$.

Composing Taylor series around $x=2^+$, we have
$$f(x)=1-2 \sqrt{x-2}+\frac{11 }{3}(x-2)+O\left((x-2)^{3/2}\right)$$
$$\lim_{x\to 2^+} \, f(x)=1\qquad \text{and} \qquad\lim_{x\to 2^+} \, f'(x)=-\infty$$

On the other side, when $x$ is large,we have
$$f(x) \sim \frac{\sqrt{4+\log
   ^2\left({x}\right)}-2}{x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$
$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \, f(x)=0^+\qquad \text{and} \qquad\lim_{x\to \infty} \, f'(x)=0^-$$

For sure, what remains to be proved is that $f'(x)$ does not show any $0$ but here I am stuck.